# VB.Net 2008 to 2012 Migration by Batch

Tags: vb.net, upgrade, batch-processing, vb6-migration

I'm upgrading a VB6 project to VB.NET 2008. I'm using last verison of VBUpgrade in VB.NET 2008, and I'm calling a batch process from CMD.

Now, I want to upgrade my VB.NET 2008 project to VB.NET 2012 project. I know that if I open the project from VB2012 the tool will ask me to upgrade it, but I have like 500 *.sln or *.vbproj and it's very hard doing it one by one.

Is there any update VB.NET 2008 to VB.NET 2012 that can be call by a Batch proces in CMD, like I did in VB6 to VB2008?

Couldn't get to work "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vcupgrade.exe".

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have not tried it but see: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/w15a82ay(v=vs.110)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/w15a82ay(v=vs.110))

Comment: @TnTinMn: you should make that an answer.